# Custom ToggleButton icon moving to corner after state change in Android

Tags: android, android-togglebutton, android-custom-drawable

I'm considerably new to Android and I'm trying to implement a custom ToggleButton in Android with help of `<selector>`tag.

When I'm not toggling the button, the icon is perfectly centered (icon size -> 32dp x 32dp ). But after toggling the button (icon size -> 24dp x 24dp ), it is weirdly running to the corner. Why is that happening?

Using Layout bounds,

[I'm finding something like this when not toggled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN4vm.jpg)

[I'm finding something like this when toggled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS33B.jpg)

code I used for

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_favo_filled"/>

<item android:state_checked="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_favo_non_filled"/>
```

Comment: The two icons filled and non-filled need to have the same size, so either make them both 32dp x 32dp or both 24dp x 24dp.

Comment: @RazvanS. so what can I do if I want the filled icon to be little small and centered when toggled? or its just not possible with ToggleButton? If not can you suggest an alternative  widget to achieve this?

Comment: Create a 32x32 image that has a smaller filled icon in the center, so more empty background.

Comment: You mean to say, to go for an ImageView instead of a ToggleButton and then add background to it?

Comment: No, just the resource that you use for your icon should have empty space inside it but maintain the same dimensions.